# Multiple random id in element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many `span` element with many `ids` such as these:

```
<span id="spn1" class="span-text">hello</span>
<span id="spn2" class="span-text">world</span>
<span id="spn3" class="span-text">12345</span>
```

It could be 1 or 100 span element. If 100 span was created so the id will be `spn100`. No problem with that. Now I have problem with javascript code because  I hardcoded the ids when the span such as these:

```
var text = $("#spn1").text() + "\r\n" + $("#spn2").text() + "\r\n" + $("#spn3").text();
```

The javascript code above was hardcoded so if 100 span was created; my copy function will not worked. How do I solve this problem?

Full code : http://jsfiddle.net/p3h7j4eb/

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What is your "copy" function? Please post that here, not at a 3rd party site. In general, using `id`s is not a great way to move forward because of how brittle the code becomes.

Comment: One solution would be to use the attribute selector, e.g. `$("[id^='spn']")` ... http://jsfiddle.net/2kmLzsr7/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CSS class as selector and just iterate over that with `$.map`. Then there's no more need for all those `id` properties:

```js
var text = $.map($(".span-text"), function(span) {
    return $(span).text();
}).join("\r\n");

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="span-text">hello</span>
<span class="span-text">world</span>
<span class="span-text">12345</span>
```

Comment: For the sake of completion it's probably worth adding a plain JavaScript answer too (`let text = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.span-text')).map((el)=>el.textContent.trim()).join('\r\n')`;).

Comment: @DavidThomas, true, although I would just use the second argument of `Array.from` instead of the `map`.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over all elements with you classname, using the `'each'` function like this:

```
var text = '';
$('.span-text').each(function ()
{
    text += $(this).text() + '\r\n';
}
```

Comment: You're missing the presumably-required `'\r\n'`.

Comment: Thanks, changed that.